# Truncation of nasm function returning value

Tags: c, if-statement, nasm

I'm using a nasm sse function returning a float value in a C program.
If I put this value directly in a if condition everything works perfectly but if I save it in a float variable it gets cut to an integer and then converted to a float. For example:

```
if(dist_cent(T,nearest_q-1,T,q,d) > k){
                        ...
}//if
```

dist_cent is my nasm function and this way I get 245.73465 as its value . If I write it like this:

```
float f = dist_cent(T,nearest_q-1,T,q,d);
if(f > k){
                        ...
}//if
```

I get 245.000000 as f value. The returning value of the nasm function is stored at the top of the x87 stack.
Is there an explanation and a way to avoid this?

Comment: Please add your print code for variable `f` and also the declaration of `k`. cf. [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: k is a float variable.
By print code you mean all the nasm code for the function dist_cent?

Comment: I was hopping some code allowing to reproduce your situation. And also check the assumption of the value contains in `f`. But I'm not user of nasm. Anyway have you exploit the doc [here](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdo11.html#section-11.3) about float numbers?